# Slicing Polygon with LineString with Python Geopandas and get the coordinates of each piece

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas

I want to slice Polygon with LineString and get coordinates of each side.

So far I got below code

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString, LinearRing, Point, Polygon

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip([0,0,1,1], [0,1,1,0]))
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[polygon_geom])

Point1 = Point(0.5,0)
Point2 = Point(,1)
line = LineString([Point1,Point2])
```

The desired result I want should be something like:

```
POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 0.5 1, 0.5 0, 0 0)), 
POLYGON ((0.5 0, 0.5 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0.5 0))
```

I tried intersect and intersection

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the relevant steps to get the solution:-

```
# Part-1 Use the original polygon geometry
# Create single-side-buffer polygons from line
left_hand_side = line.buffer(5, single_sided=True)
right_hand_side = line.buffer(-5, single_sided=True)

# Spatial difference operation between 2 polygons
left_part = polygon_geom.difference(right_hand_side)
print(left_part.wkt)  #left part of the split polygon

right_part = polygon_geom.difference(left_hand_side)
print(right_part.wkt)  #right part of the split polygon
```

The output:

```
POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 0.5 1, 0.5 0, 0 0))
POLYGON ((0.5 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0.5 0, 0.5 1))
```

```
# Part-2 Works on the polygon geodataframe
# The results are the same
left_part = polygon.difference(right_hand_side)
print(left_part[0].wkt)

right_part = polygon.difference(left_hand_side)
print(right_part[0].wkt)
```

Comment: This wont work if shape changes

Comment: @Puzzlemaster Show us your code that does not work.